# Is it possible to put another element (button) inside a Checkboxlist Item?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, asp.net-ajax

I have a CheckBoxList that is populated via DataSource (each one with it's value coming from a database so I can't hard-code anything inside it), and I need to Add a button for details on the right side of an specific Item of the CheckBoxList when some event is fired.

Can i do that? how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each item in the `CheckBoxList` is a `ListItem` object. These don't inherit from `Control` so they don't have their own [ControlCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.aspx) property. This means you can't add a LinkButton or `Button` to the item(s).

If it was based on a `Control` object, you'd be able to hook into the `OnDataBound` event of the `CheckBoxList`, and iterate through the items until you find the one that needs the button. From there you'd be able to add the control (button) to the individual item's `item.Controls` collection. But you're going to be pretty limited for the ListItem because it doesn't have this functionality.

What does the details button do? If it's simply a client-side button, you could maybe inject html into the Text property of the `ListItem`, although I haven't verified this works:

```
foreach (ListItem item in myCheckBoxList)
{
     item.Text += "&nbsp;<input type=\"button\"/>";
}
```

Either way it won't be pretty, and you might be better to create a simple user control. In the control you could still use a CheckBoxList, but you could add HyperLink or Buttons to the UserControl dynamically. You could use CSS or other means to lay out the button in the right spot.

Comment: Thank you :)
I'm still not sure on how to create a "simple user control" to do this

Comment: No problem. If you haven't worked with UserControls in the past, here's a good place to start:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3w5b53.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write a custom user control if you want to do that.